# Are questions about non-English lyric translations on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask how the lyrics to some songs written in languages other than English are translated. Would it be on-topic for me to ask for the translation for the lyrics of a specific song?

Comment: Related: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/19449/27810

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions.

> how the lyrics to some songs written in languages other than English are translated

This could *potentially* be a good question.  Like poetry, translating music has some important nuances to it that would make this answer relevant to music fans.

> Would it be on-topic for me to ask for the translation for the lyrics of a specific song?

No, I don't think we want to be a place to request lyrics or translation services.

Answer (score 4):

I personally would appreciate if we could talk about interesting lyrics here on MF, but we should not start a translating service. People can try to translate lyrics on their own (if nothing else works: translate.google.com).

Instead, I would rather suggest to support questions about interpreting some lyrics and discussing their meanings. The question posters should provide original lyrics and their translation (or the relevant parts of it) and ask what the artist wants to express there.

Agree? I know that there could be some bad or broad questions be created on that topic, but I think the majority would be interesting.